# What is the best way to quote unquoted strings while leaving already quoted strings alone?

Tags: python, json, regex, string, sed

I have a large block of text that is almost JSON, but is not quite. I need to make it JSON so that I can process it. Specifically, it is the "marks" object in the code at the following page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Syrian_Civil_War_detailed_map

Some of the strings there are already quoted. Some of them are not. I need to quote all the strings and leave the already-quoted ones alone. For example, with the following almost-JSON-object:

```
marks = {
    lat = 36.103,
    long = 37.308,
    mark = m.gov_hill,
    marksize = 184,
    label = "[[Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)|Aleppo]]",
    link = "Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)",
    label_size = 0,
    position = "left"
}
```

I need it to become this:

```
"marks" = {
    "lat" = 36.103,
    "long" = 37.308,
    "mark" = "m.gov_hill",
    "marksize" = 184,
    "label" = "[[Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)|Aleppo]]",
    "link" = "Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)",
    "label_size" = 0,
    "position" = "left"
}
```

Essentially, anything that can become a string and is not already a string should be turned into a string. Also, I already have a sed command for turning the equals signs into colons as one of the steps to turning it into valid JSON, so no need to comment on that part of the process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have left the last line unquoted as the solutions you're getting are assuming things about terminating `,`s. Also having a date like `02.14.2016` or an IP address or any other digit-dot combinations and `foo = bar` on the right side of your assignments would break most solutions. Think again about your sample input and see if you can come up with the worst case rather than just a sunny day case.

Answer (score 1):

With a regex as

```
(^[^\n\S]*|=\s*)(?![\d\s])(\w+[^,\s]*)
```

and a replacement of

```
\1"\2"
```

you would get [these results](https://regex101.com/r/mQ9rI9/1). You can switch from Python to any other flavor, if you think you will be using a different regex language/engine.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer showed you how to apply it in python for the given question input

Comment: That linked site has "code generator" on the left, which basically gives a python-ready string: https://regex101.com/r/mQ9rI9/1/codegen?language=python

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This looks for any lines that does not already have any `"` characters.  For those lines have an alphabetic character or an underline after the equal sign, then the quantity after the equal sign is placed in quotes:

```
$ sed -E '/"/!s/= +(.*[[:alpha:]_].*),/= "\1",/' file
marks = {
    lat = 36.103,
    long = 37.308,
    mark = "m.gov_hill",
    marksize = 184,
    label = "[[Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)|Aleppo]]",
    link = "Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)",
    label_size = 0,
    position = "left"
}
```

In more detail:

- `-E`

  This tells sed to use extended regular expressions.
- `/"/!`

  This tells sed to remove from consideration any line that already has double quotes.
- `s/= +(.*[[:alpha:]_].*),/= "\1",/`

  This substitute command puts the quantity after the equal sign in double quotes if the quantity has either an alphabetic character or an underline character.

#### Changing the file in place

To change a file in place, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak -E '/"/!s/= +(.*[[:alpha:]_].*),/= "\1",/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Process each line of text separately (assumes items do not span across lines)

Strip off the trailing comma

Split each line at the first equals sign

For each sub-item produced by splitting:

- Strip off leading/trailing spaces
- If it's equal to `{` or `}`, leave it alone.
- If `int()` or `float()` succeed, leave it alone.
- If it starts with a quote, leave it alone (assumes no imbalanced quotes)
- Otherwise add quotes

Reassemble the processed lines, adding the commas back as necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/=/ {
    lhs = rhs = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",lhs)
    sub(/^[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",rhs)

    sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"\"&\"",lhs)

    if ( rhs !~ /^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|".*"),?$/ ) {
        sub(/,?$/,"\"&",rhs)
        rhs = "\"" rhs
    }

    $0 = lhs " = " rhs
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"marks" = "{"
    "lat" = 36.103,
    "long" = 37.308,
    "mark" = "m.gov_hill",
    "marksize" = 184,
    "label" = "[[Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)|Aleppo]]",
    "link" = "Battle of Aleppo (2012–present)",
    "label_size" = 0,
    "position" = "left"
}
```

The above should work even for the non-trivial  cases I mentioned in my comment under your question.